# mapping Struct to bytes32 can't read from map

Tags: solidity, remix

I am saving under byte32 key some struct, it is saved, but I really trust it is saved at all.  When try to read, I get 0x0 in all fields.

```
mapping (bytes32 => Document) documents;
bytes32[] public documentHashMap;

function setDocument(bytes32  _hash, string memory _documentName, bytes32 _documentHash) public {
     Document memory document = documents[_hash];

     document.id = documentCount++;
     document.documentName = _documentName;
     document.documentHash = _documentHash;
     document.sender = msg.sender;

    documentHashMap.push(_hash) -1;
}

function getDocumentByHash(bytes32 _hash) view public returns(uint, string memory, bytes32, address) {
    return (documents[_hash].id, documents[_hash].documentName, documents[_hash].documentHash, documents[_hash].sender);
}
```

There is something wrong in in set method?

Comment: You probably wanna change that `memory` to `storage`, otherwise you're just creating a local `Document` rather than referencing your `documents` mapping.

Comment: Alternatively, you could declare `Document memory document` at the beginning of the function, then initialize the fields of this object as you are already doing, and finally set `documents[_hash] = document` at the end of the function.

Comment: I gave you the second option because I don't recall ever actually trying the first option, so although it makes sense to me, it might not be feasible in Solidity.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking this should be memory. I was making example pre 0.5.0, and fitting it across docs.

Comment: NP. Just don't forgot to mention which one of these two options worked for you.

Comment: BTW, adding `-1` after calling `push` really isn't necessary. I keep seeing it across various questions here, and it always makes me wonder what on earth programmers are thinking when they add it there (how could it possibly affect anything?). In short, `push` returns the new length of the array, so "push minus 1" gives the old length of the array. But since this value is not stored or used anywhere, it is pointless to generate it.

Comment: Also thanks for clarification about that '-1' ^^ . I am using storage change and works perfect! I was wondering about purpose of editing length.I have to save your comment.

Comment: The `-1` doesn't "edit length". `push` returns the length, and "push - 1` returns the length minus 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. Change `memory` to `storage`, otherwise you're just creating a local `Document` object rather than referencing your `documents` mapping.
2. Declare `Document memory document` at the beginning of the function, then initialize the fields of this object (as you are already doing), and finally set `documents[_hash] = document` at the end of the function.